# Create a 3d rotating mouse-tracking wall of tiles navigation using javascript, html5 and css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, 3d

I've been searching and I can't find anything on the web, but I'm interested in creating (or using something already available, hopefully since I'm pressed with time) similar to this site:
http://www.citroen.hr/citroen/#/citroen/

It's also similar to the Safari Top Sites view, but has the added mouse-tracking and 3d rotation.

Does anyone know of something similar created with javascript/html/css or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is a bit too general to get a good answer too. But based on what you have written, I would suggest the javascript book by David Flanagan. Good Luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic version with HTML elements, CSS 3D transforms (so [*it only works in browsers supporting 3D transforms & nesting of 3D transformed elements - this means no Opera and no IE*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)) and a little bit of JavaScript for the mouse tracking:

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/LpcqD)

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='tiles'>
  <li class='tile'></li>
  <!-- more tiles; I used 16 for the demo and put them on an icosagon -->
</ul>
<div class='slider'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.tiles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-162deg);
}    
.tile {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0.5em -10em;
  width: 20em; height: 20em;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* inradius of an icosagon */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.tile:hover { opacity: 1; }
.tile:nth-child(odd) { bottom: 100%; }
.tile:nth-child(2), .tile:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(18deg) translateZ(-66.29439em);
}
/* and so on... in general, something of the form: 
.tile:nth-child(2*i), .tile:nth-child(2*i-1) {
  transform: rotateY(1*18deg) translateZ(-66.29439em);
}
where 18deg = outer angle of the icosagon 
66.29439em = 1.05*20em*(1 + sqrt(5) + sqrt(5 + 2*sqrt(5)))/2 
           = 1.05 * inradius of icosagon
see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Icosagon.html */
.tile:nth-child(1) {
  background: url(image1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
/* and so on, set backgrounds for each */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%; left: 10%;
  height: 0.25em; width: 80%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: grey 
    linear-gradient(90deg, crimson 100%, transparent 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 5% 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
(function(){
  var b = document.body;
  
  b.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var w = b.clientWidth, x = e.clientX, 
        perc = x/w, 
        full_angle = -162, 
        to_angle = full_angle + (100 - perc)*full_angle, 
        txt = 'rotateY(' + to_angle + 'deg)', 
        prefixes = ['Webkit', 'Moz', /*'ms', 'O', */''], 
        len = prefixes.length, 
        property = 'Transform',
        a = document.querySelector('.tiles'), 
        s = document.querySelector('.slider');
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(prefixes[i] == '')
        property = property.toLowerCase();
      a.style[prefixes[i] + property] = txt;
    }
    s.style.backgroundPosition = (perc*100 - .5) + '% 50%';
  }, false);
}());
```